# Is there an encyclopedic book with all the various formatting styles found in novel since the beginning of history?

Tags: creative-writing, formatting, references

Is there an encyclopedic book with all the various formatting styles found in novel since the beginning of history? I would like to read one to see what are all the different formatting options you can use to write a novel from the Biblical style of old to the modern style used by mainstream authors such as Stephen King.

Comment: Are you sure you mean formatting? What in particular are you interested in?

Comment: formatting as to how to introduce dialogues, if you should use chapters, etc.

Comment: I suggest you reword your question as it is unclear whether you're asking about visual layout, or literary style. If the former, two excellent books which touch on the topic are Peter Szendy's 'Of Stigmatology' and Jed Rasula and Steve MacCaffery's (eds) 'Imagining Language: An Anthology'.